# jquery mobile: 2 popups/dialogs opened simultaneously

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

this question is similar to the common question about 'chaining' jqm popups (*FYI ... answer is: use a settimeout to call 2nd popup*).

**However**, I am looking for a solution to have 2 popups open *at the same time*.

Specifically, I have popup that shows a user's shopping cart items. Each item has an X-button to allow the user to remove/delete the item. But the X-button (delete action) needs to issue a confirm-delete dialog (popup). Thus the shopping cart popup would be open, and on top of it would be the confirm-delete popup/dialog.

Comment: its not possible to have more than one active popup (jQM widget) at the same time. Solution: create a secondary custom popup (not jQM widget).

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034745/show-raw-jquery-mobile-simple-dialog-above-another-raw-jquery-mobile-simple-dial/19040835#19040835 using simpledialog2 jQM plugin. Dem: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/QpFPu/ try clicking close dialog without selecting a checkbox.

Comment: "Omar" answer is right.. check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572518/can-you-create-nested-popups-with-jquerymobile/22574003#22574003

Comment: the only problem with the "create a secondary not-jqm widget" is that I may as well just completely scrap the jqm popup completely.