# Is it possible to open popup in popup(parent) in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery mobile 1.4.2. 
Is it possible to open popup(child popup) in popup(parent popup) ?

I tried this way,

```
<a href="#pop1" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">pop1</a> 

<div data-role="popup" id="pop1" data-dismissible="false"> 
 Parent popup
 <a href="#pop2" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">popup 2</a> 
 <div data-role="popup" id="pop2" data-dismissible="false"> 
   Child Popup
 </div>

</div>
```

But this does not working.. Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the popup api docs : http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/, it states the following:

> The framework does not currently support chaining of popups so it's not possible to embed a link from one popup to another popup. All links with a data-rel="popup" inside a popup will not do anything at all.

If you need to have one popup open on top of another you will have to use a different plugin or roll your own.  You can see my answer to another question [Show raw jquery mobile simple dialog above another raw jquery mobile simple dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034745/show-raw-jquery-mobile-simple-dialog-above-another-raw-jquery-mobile-simple-dial/19040835#19040835) where I used the Simpledialog2 plugin to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409895/how-can-i-open-a-second-jquery-mobile-popup-from-the-first-popup) and was referred here. Following the [popup api](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/) link above, I found a simple solution that doesn't involve a plug in.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
  $('#del').click(function (e) { // e is the event
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#popupDelete").popup("open")
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmdavis62/7AuNC/3/) to demo this.